# Finding the distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is a continuous random variable with a cdf of $F(x)$. If we let $Y=F(X)$. What is the distribution of $Y$?

I am unsure how to approach this problem. All I have is the following:

$F(x)=P(X\leq x)$

$F(y)=P(Y\leq y) = P(F(X)\leq y)$

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What are the possible values of Y, to begin with?

Comment: Try to pictue the event $\{F(X)\le y\}$ using a graph of the cdf $F$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: How can we justify writing something like...
$$ \mathbb{P}( Y \leq y ) = \mathbb{P} (F(X) \leq y) = \mathbb{P} ( X \leq F^{-1}(y) ) $$

Comment: Got it. Thanks!